# Bootstrap Drop down navigation in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following navigation on `MVC` using bootstrap, how can I make the Storage Menu Link (second `li` ) as a drowndown to include Add and View Links without removing the `@ActionLink`?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="brand" href="/Home/Home">News Library</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="@ActiveLink("Home", "Home", null)">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", "Home")</li>
                    <li class="@ActiveLink("About", "Home", null)">@Html.ActionLink("Storage", "Add", "Storage")</li>
                    <li class="@ActiveLink("Contact", "Home", null)">@Html.ActionLink("Activites", "Add", "Activites")</li>
                    <li class="@ActiveLink("Contact", "Home", null)">@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Index", "Search")</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("[Log Out]", "Logout", "Home")</li>
                </ul>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "How can I make the storage as a dropdown..." Your request is unclear.

Comment: @rikket Do you mean you want to show another dropdown when you hover second link?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<li class="@ActiveLink("Home", "Home", null) dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Storage
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Storage", "Add", "Storage")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Storage", "View", "Storage")</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

[See the bootstrap site for more information](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav)

Comment: It is giving me error as 
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

I am using bootstrap 3.3.7